# Can I calculate the time that should be spent for running my code on a pixel?

Tags: performance, time, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a 5576x9444 image and I'm going to write a parallelized code that will take 6 days as maximum to completely be run on this image on a computer with the following configuration:

- RAM: 12
- CPU: Corei7 frequency 3GHz
- Graphic: geoforce 8400 gs

My code is a code that is the same for each pixel and it should be run on each pixel.
Is there a way how much time should the code take to be run on a single pixel? (at least approximately)

Comment: Well, no more than 10 miliseconds per pixel (no magic here, just division). But that doesn't mean that the benchmark on 1 pixel must be below that threshold, that would be a latency measurement when it's really about throughput.

Comment: @harold in fact I've done that division and I want to see if that division is right? I will add a picture to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use down-sampling of the image by different factors....and then see if total execution time is exactly proportional to the no of pixels in the down sampled image. Then you can take decision to weather or not to use division of total time by total no of pixels...!!